# Json Slupper assert and extract

Tags: json, groovy, extract, soapui, assert

I'm using the next Json

```
   {
  "ID": 8,
  "MenuItems": [
    {
      "ID": 38,
      "Name": "Home",
      "URL": "{\"PageLayout\":\"Home\",\"Icon\":\"home\"}",
      "Culture": "en",
      "Children": null
    },
    {
      "ID": 534,
      "Name": "GUIDE ",
      "URL": "{''PageLayout'':''Page A'', ''Icon'':''A''}",
      "MenuType": 1,
      "PageID": 0,
      "Culture": "en",
      "Children": [
        {
          "ID": 6,
          "Name": "Form A",
          "URL": "[''Type'':''Form A'',''Icon'':''Form'',''ItemID'':\"358\"]",
          "Culture": "he",
          "RuleID": 0
        },
        {
          "ID": 60,
          "Name": "Drama",
          "URL": "[''Type'':''Form B'',''Icon'':''Form'',''ItemID'':\"3759\"]",
          "Culture": "en",
          "RuleID": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i'm using Groovy script in soapUI and i need to:

1. Assert the exitance of node that has the name GUIDE
2. Extract a list of all Itemsid

Comment: This is even not a valid JSON.

Comment: If you are just asking for someone to do your job, then StackOverflow is not the place. Please, tell us what you already tried and what errors you receive - that way you will get some help right on the spot. Also, the above is still not a valid JSON, thus, the solution might be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON content using JsonSlurper and then work with the results like so:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// Assuming your JSON is stored in "jsonString"
def jsonContent = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

// Assert node exists with name GUIDE
assert(jsonContent.MenuItems.Name.contains("GUIDE"))

// Get list of ItemIDs
def itemList = jsonContent.MenuItems.Children.URL.ItemID[0].toList()
// List the items
itemList.each {log.info it}
```

Note that the above will fail given your current example, because of a few issues. Firstly, Name contains "GUIDE " (trailing space) rather than "GUIDE" (so you will need to adapt accordingly). Secondly, it is invalid JSON; the URL nodes have various erroneous characters.

On a side note, if you first need to retrieve your JSON from the response associated with a previous TestStep (say one called "SendMessage") within the existing testCase, this can be done as follows:

```
def jsonString = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("SendMessage").testRequest.response.getContentAsString()
```